# Mercurial merge changeset between branches brings all ancestors with it

Tags: merge, mercurial, tortoisehg

I have a problem with merging changes between branches.

I have default branch `default`.

When I'm starting working under new issue I make new branch like #565 from `default` and working with it. After working I'm merging code changes from #565 into `default` - it work great.

Also I have branch `anotherbranch` - this is like production branch, we can merge something there if it was tested on `default`.

Sometime I need to merge code changes from #565 into `anotherbranch`. When I trying to do this, Mercurial offer me to merge ALL code changes between #565 AND `anotherbranch` (because #565 is child of `default`).

How I can merge ONLY code changes of #565?

Answer (score 4):

Someone suggested the graft command, and that's probably what you'll end up using, but let me take a step back and suggest that this problem will go away if you improve your process a bit.

In general if you fix bugs in new branches branched from `anotherbranch` and add new features in branches from `default` you'll have the best of both worlds.  Fix bugs off of your "production" branch and then merge that production branch, called `anotherbranch`, back into `default` immediately.

That's the usual process and that makes sure that the bug fixes are everywhere but that new features don't hit production until they've gotten good testing.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is the [graft command](http://www.selenic.com/hg/help/graft) ("copy changes from other branches onto the current branch").

Answer (score 0):

The best way to fix this is, as Ry4an suggests, to modify your workflow. You may also want to consider using the [mq extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MqExtension) to create patches. Patches are a great way to apply only certain changes to a repository, particularly if you're not ready for a full-on merge.